# PySpark: column dtype changes in performing union

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have three dataframes stored in a list `data_multi`. Each of these dataframes have the same column names and also same dtypes

*columns*

```
>>> set(data_multi[0].columns) == set(data_multi[1].columns)  == set(data_multi[2].columns)
True
```

*dtypes (showing only one column)*

```
>>> data_multi[0].select('aml_id_key_12739').dtypes
[('aml_id_key_12739', 'bigint')]

>>> data_multi[1].select('aml_id_key_12739').dtypes
[('aml_id_key_12739', 'bigint')]

>>> data_multi[2].select('aml_id_key_12739').dtypes
[('aml_id_key_12739', 'bigint')]
```

I copied a function mentioned from a post on SO that unions(rbinds) all dataframes

```
def unionAll(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

Using this, I union the three dataframes to get a single one
data_single = unionAll(*ddata_multi)

This is where I am facing a problem. The `aml_id_key_12739` column in each dataframe is a `'bigint'` but right after the union it becomes a `'double'`

```
>>> pprint(data_single.select('aml_id_key_12739').dtypes)
[('aml_id_key_12739', 'double')]
```

Because of this my whole id column is messed up. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Is columns order the same in all dataframe?

Comment: @Rumoku I just realised that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the bug. The problem is that spark will simply append the dataframes. it will not append by using columns names.

If you are using union then you should make sure the columns in the dataframe appear in same order because the appending appears to be happening in the order they appear.

In this example, I have reversed the order of columns and the values in the second dataframe(`df_2`) and then took a union.

```
>>> df_1 = spark.createDataFrame([['a',1]], ['col_1', 'col_2'])
>>> df_2 = spark.createDataFrame([[2,'b']], ['col_2', 'col_1'])
>>> df_3 = unionAll(*[df_1, df_2])
>>> df_3
DataFrame[col_1: string, col_2: string]
>>> df_3.show()
+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|
+-----+-----+
|    a|    1|
|    2|    b|
+-----+-----+
```

And now when I use the correct order, I get the expected output

```
>>> df_3 = unionAll(*[df_1.select(*['col_1', 'col_2']), df_2.select(*['col_1', 'col_2'])])
>>> df_3.show()
+-----+-----+                                                                   
|col_1|col_2|
+-----+-----+
|    a|    1|
|    b|    2|
+-----+-----+
```